# Generating parser in Python language from JavaCC source?

Tags: python, parsing, javacc

I do mean the `???` in the title because I'm not exactly sure. Let me explain the situation.

I'm not a computer science student & I never did any compilers course. Till now I used to think that compiler writers or students who did compilers course are outstanding because they had to write Parser component of the compiler in whatever language they are writing the compiler. It's not an easy job right?

I'm dealing with Information Retrieval problem. My desired programming language is Python.

**Parser Nature:**
http://ir.iit.edu/~dagr/frDocs/fr940104.0.txt is the sample corpus. This file contains around 50 documents with some XML style markup. (You can see it in above link). I need to note down other some other values like `<DOCNO> FR940104-2-00001 </DOCNO>` & `<PARENT> FR940104-2-00001 </PARENT>` and I only need to index the `<TEXT> </TEXT>` portion of document which contains some varying tags which I need to strip down and a lot of `<!-- -->` comments that are to be neglected and some `&hyph; &space; &amp;` character entities. I don't know why corpus has things like this when its know that it's neither meant to be rendered by browser nor a proper XML document.

I thought of using any Python XML parser and extract desired text. But after little searching I found [JavaCC parser source code (Parser.jj)](http://www.ir.iit.edu/~dagr/IRCourse/Project/Parser.jj) for the same corpus I'm using [here](http://www.ir.iit.edu/~dagr/cs529/project.html). A quick look up on [JavaCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaCC) followed by  [Compiler-compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_generator) revealed that after all compiler writers aren't as great as I thought. They use Compiler-compiler to generate parser code in desired language. Wiki says input to compiler-compiler is input is a grammar (usually in BNF). This is where I'm lost.

1. Is [Parser.jj](http://www.ir.iit.edu/~dagr/IRCourse/Project/Parser.jj) the grammar (Input to compiler-compiler called JavaCC)? It's definitely not BNF. What is this grammar called? Why is this grammar has Java language? Isn't there any universal grammar language?
2. I want python parser for parsing the corpus. Is there any way I can translate Parser.jj to get python equivalent?  If yes, what is it? If no, what are my other options?
3. By any chance does any one know what is this corpus? Where is its original source? I would like to see some description for it. It is distributed on internet with name `frDocs.tar.gz`

Comment: Don't be fooled by the existence of JavaCC, SableCC, ANTLR, boost::spirit, lepl, pyparsing etc. Writing a decent **compiler** is still art, sometimes even black art. Also, it really helps to know what you're doing when you want to come up with a good parser / lexer etc., so don't be tricked into thinking all that people do is fire up a program from the command line.

Comment: "This file contains around 50 documents with some XML style markup".  It doesn't have a proper `<?xml` header, but it sure likes like XML.  It might -- actually -- be SGML.  Why not simply use an XML parser?  Why waste time reinventing that wheel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you call this "XML-style" markup? - this looks like pretty standard/basic XML to me.
Try elementTree or lxml. Instead of writing a parser, use one of the stable, well-hardened libraries that are already out there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't build a parser - let alone a whole compiler - from a(n E)BNF grammar - it's just the grammar, i.e. syntax (and some syntax, like Python's indentation-based block rules, can't be modeled in it at all), not the semantics. Either you use seperate tools for these aspects, or use a more advances framework (like Boost::Spirit in C++ or Parsec in Haskell) that unifies both.

JavaCC (like yacc) is responsible for generating a parser, i.e. the subprogram that makes sense of the tokens read from the source code. For this, they mix a (E)BNF-like notation with code written in the language the resulting parser will be in (for e.g. building a parse tree) - in this case, Java. Of course it would be possible to make up another language - but since the existing languages can handle those tasks relatively well, it would be rather pointless. And since other parts of the compiler might be written by hand in the same language, it makes sense to leave the "I got ze tokens, what do I do wit them?" part to the person who will write these other parts ;)

I never heard of "PythonCC", and google didn't either (well, theres a "pythoncc" project on google code, but it's describtion just says "pythoncc is a program that tries to generate optimized machine Code for Python scripts." and there was no commit since march). Do you mean [any of these python parsing libraries/tools?](http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing) But I don't think there's a way to automatically convert the javaCC code to a Python equivalent - but the whole thing looks rather simple, so if you dive in and learn a bit about parsing via javaCC and [python library/tool of your choice], you might be able to translate it...

Comment: sorry! there is no PythonCC. I wrote it just to mean the equivalence with JavaCC. I removed that part my question.

Comment: "[python library/tool of your choice]" can you suggest a [python library/tool of your choice]?

Comment: @claws: LEPL (http://www.acooke.org/lepl/) looks great, but I never actually parsed anything with Python, so I can't speak from experience.